# Separate keys and values from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like :

```
var obj1 = [{ first : 1, second : 2 },
            {third : 3, fourth : 4},
            {fifth : 5, sixth : 6}];
```

I want to separate the `keys` and `values` into 2 different `arrays` such that the result should be

```
var labels = [first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth];
var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

I tried this :

```
var labels = [];
var values = [];
for(var key in obj1[0]){
    labels.push(key);
    values.push(obj1[0][key]);
}
```

But it results in

```
labels = ["first","second"];
values = [1,2];
```

I know this happens because I am iterating only the `0` index position. Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve the expected output.

Comment: is jquery possible to use?

Comment: @pc-shooter I was thinking a pure javascript solution. But if jquery gives a better solution thens its fine to use jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```js
var obj1 = [{ first : 1, second : 2 },
            {third : 3, fourth : 4},
            {fifth : 5, sixth : 6}]; 

var key=[];
var value=[];
obj1.forEach(function(item){
 
  for(i in item)
  {
    key.push(i);
    value.push(item[i]);
  }
   
});

console.log(key);
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Is there no way to avoid 2 for loops?

Comment: Your one is array object . if you want to get all object from your data list you have to iterate the whole object

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
    for (var key in obj1[i]) {
        labels.push(key);
        values.push(obj1[i][key]);
    }
}
```