# How to get property name and value from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so i have object that have many properties, i need to get all values and property names from that object, i'm not sure what is best and easiest way to do it. I already tried few methods but didn't had any luck with it

```
angular.forEach(array, function(value, key){
   console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147983/separate-keys-and-values-from-object

Comment: What is wrong with this approach? You have the key and the value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

forEach works with arrays, for object properties you need:

```
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log(property, ' ', object[property]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You beat me on the time, this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which returns an array of the keys of  the object. For instance :

```
var obj = { 0 : "a", 1 : "b", 2 : "c"};
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // [0, 1, 2]
```

You can also use the [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) which returns an array of the values of an object :

```
var obj = { 0 : "a", 1 : "b", 2 : "c"};
console.log(Object.values(obj)); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

you can achive with two foreach in angular like below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   
  </body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name =[
   {
     "Name": "myname",
     "Password": "mypasscode"
   },
   {
     "Name": "yourname",
     "Password": "yourcasscode"
   }
];
 angular.forEach($scope.name, function(k , v) {
        angular.forEach(k, function(x , y) {
            alert(y+"--"+x);
        })
    })
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, already got solution from Luis Sieira's answer.